# Getting error for xlsx-style after entering command 'yarn start'

Tags: angular6, xlsx, js-xlsx

i imported xlsx-style package to style my xlsx stylesheet,then i did 'yarn start'.after that i got error here am attaching error

Error:

Webpack: Finished after 84.273 seconds.

ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                4:08:23 PM

This dependency was not found:

- fs in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js, ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs

This relative module was not found:

- ./cptable in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/dist/cpexcel.js
  ERROR in /home/administrator/Documents/jan21/pgh/src/main/webapp/app/entities/configuration/financial-year-settings.component.ts(37,9):
  TS2305: Module '"/home/administrator/Documents/jan21/pgh/src/main/webapp/app/entities/service/calendarexcel.service"' has no exported member 'CalendarExcelService'.
  Version: typescript 2.7.2
  Time: 54018ms
  ✖ ｢wdm｣:    1772 modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed my error by giving this code in webpack.config.js,here code is :

```
node: {
 fs: 'empty'
 },
 externals: [ {
 './cptable': 'var cptable' 
} ]
```

Comment: i don't have a webpack.config.js in my angular 11 project, how can i do it?